# Do SharePoint 2013 JavaScript Client object model support run with elevated privileges code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

Can I elevate Visitors Group users permission via javascript client object model code to do some list or library item updates ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot elevate privileges in JavaScript CSOM, nor would you want to.  Remember there is nothing stopping end users from crafting their own scripts and running them via a developer tool like IE's Developer Tools or Firebug.  If you could elevate privileges via JavaScript, it could mean disaster on your Farm as regular users could just write a script to elevate their permissions and make some major changes.

If you need to do this from the browser, look at either a custom application page or a web service that could run on a server where you could properly elevate privileges.

Refer below links:

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ef752641-63e9-400b-a7e7-f7d74d7ee533/run-csom-javascript-code-with-elevated-privileges)

[Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028970/elevated-privileges-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Elevating privileges in JavaScript Object Model  is not supported in SharePoint 2010 as well as SharePoint 2013. However if you need to work with a specific object such as a list or a web then we can use the SharePoint Add-In model (App model) to create an add-in with an App-only Authorization to grant access to the specific object while installing the app.The app designer would have to specify the required access levels in the app manifest while implementing the app.

Answer (score 2):

In 2010 it is not possible, not sure about sharepoint 2013.You may refer,

http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/tag/apps-for-sharepoint/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/835b0d48-8fb5-47d4-bc1a-502c18f59568/runwithelevatedprivileges-in-share-point-client-object-model